# is if(s.length()) saying that if it returns a value, proceed?

Tags: c++

Typically, I see code with say `if(s.length() > 1) ...`, but here it only has `if(s.length())`.

The `length` function is implemented as mentioned below. When used in the `test3` function call within the file containing `int main()`, is `if(s.length)` saying that if it returns a count that is greater than zero then it will execute the body of that `if` statement?

```
int statistician::length() const
{
    return count;
}
```

Code (`test3()` call in `int main()`):

```
statistician s, t, u, v;

if (s.length( ) || t.length( )) return 0; // <-- HERE
if (s.sum( ) || t.sum( )) return 0;

t.next(5);
u.next(0); u.next(10); u.next(10); u.next(20);

v = s + s;
if (v.length( ) || v.sum( )) return 0;
v = s + u;
if (!(u == v)) return 0;
v = t + s;
```

Comment: A value of `0` is convertible to boolean `false` and any non-zero value is `true`. So `if (s.length() )` is the same as `if (s.length() != 0 )`

Comment: `if(x)` is exactly equivalent to `if ((x) != 0)`  (where `x` is not of class type, that is)

Comment: My water shed comment. For the reason that negative numbers and the fact that it could have been a typo, it’s always best to be explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `c++` an `int` can be implicitly converted to a bool. The rule is:

```
int (0) -> false
int (anything else) -> true
```

In your case, the length will return some positive number if it exists, and 0 if it doesn't so this logic:

```
if (s.length())
```

Is equivalent to

```
if (s.length() >= 1)
               ^ // Very important, you probably missed this, but you probably
                 // want to know if the string is greater than 0, not "2 or more"
```

for the way you have probably implemented it. **However!** `int` can also be negative, and negative values are still not 0, and therefore also will be `true`. So if your function was something like this:

```
int length() {
   if (some condition) {
       return -1; // error code
   }
   return count;
}
```

Then your if statements are suddenly **not** equivalent. So, ...
best thing to do if this is not the case, is to represent your data as you intend it. AKA, if your count value can't be negative, then do not allow it to be. Use an `unsigned int`, or `size_t`:

```
size_t length();
```

Comment: there's also the different case `s.length() == 1`

Comment: In the .cpp implemented code of the class, there is no chance of count ever being negative. It is initialized to zero. It increases by one per another function call (next())…. I also do think the value type of count in the header file is of size_t by using ‘typedef size_t int’. Thank you for this reminder. Would using  assert() be another way of approaching this non-negative outcome?

Comment: `typedef size_t int` ! No don't do that! Both of these are keywords, this shouldn't work. Just use `size_t` then you do not have to worry.